# Hyperlinking a cell to another cell in the same worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, hyperlink

I'd like if x is clicked under column A, the green rectangle moves to the 1 to the farthest right: Clicking first x at A1 arrives at (1, P3), A2 -> (2, P2), A3 -> (3, P2), A4 -> (4, P3).

[image: Screenshot]

I've written the code with an intention to hyperlink A1, A2, A3, and A4 to corresponding PCell. How do I fetch the 1's on the farthest right under the P columns?

Is there is another way to do it?

```
Sub GoToPCell()

Dim i As Integer, PCell As String

PCell =


For i = 1 To 4

ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Cells(i, 1), Address:="", SubAddress:="'" & Sheet1.Name & "'!PCell"


Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Use `Cells(i, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)` to determine the column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Mr. BigBen comment the main part to solve your problem. I have just post full sub as below. Try...

```
Sub GoToPCell()
Dim i As Integer, PCell As String
    For i = 1 To 4
        PCell = Cells(i, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Address
        ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Cells(i, 1), Address:="", SubAddress:="'" & Sheet1.Name & "'!" & PCell
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: @cd3091 If you found the answer useful then you should accept (tick as green) the answer so that other user can know your problem is solved. Thanks.