# Hyperlinking to a specific cell in the same worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, hyperlink

I applied to the solution that I got from [Hyperlinking a cell to another cell in the same worksheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58869211/hyperlinking-a-cell-to-another-cell-in-the-same-worksheet) to a bigger worksheet where there are columns other than P1, P2, and P3. For instance, there are many columns after P3, and some among P1, P2, and P3. But clicking the x's, all of them arrived at the cells in the last column even when they were all empty.I just want the x's to take to the corresponding one in P, ignoring the rest of the columns. How do I fix the code?

Sub GoToPCell()

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim PCell As String

For i = 2 To 5
PCell = Cells(i, "FJ").End(xlToLeft).Address
ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Cells(i, 2), Address:="", SubAddress:="'" & Sheet1.Name & "'!" & PCell

Next i

End Sub
```

[image: Hyperlink Img]

Comment: You change `Cells(i, Columns.Count)` to `Cells(i, whatevercolumnisafterthelastP)`.

Comment: That takes to the last nonempty value in the column to the farthest right. I defined again PCell before that line: PCell = ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 99 to 165 Step 6) but there is an error at '99 to 165 Step 6'. The reason is that Column P's exist at columns 99, 105, 111, … ,165. Do you know how to fix that syntax and would that fix the issue? Thank you.

Comment: If I understand your setup correctly, try `Cells(i, 166)`.

Comment: It works the same as your 1st suggestion, not arriving at the last P column with nonempty value. How do you define locations of Column P's?

Comment: I don't understand why `PCell` is inside the loop, or why the `j` loop is needed.

Comment: I just did. Using that code with Cells(i,j) or Cells(i,j+1) works the same as you suggested.

Comment: @BigBen I just edited the code again. It's getting Application-defined or object-defined error at PCell = ..

Comment: Because `i` is 0. Move that line inside the loop.

Comment: I did, it's back to your suggestion.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of where the hyperlink gets added?

Comment: @BigBen Just did! So supposed to arrive under the blue P1.

Comment: What column letter or number is that?

Comment: 135. About in the middle of 99, 105, ..., 165.

Comment: I don't think using `End` is going to work here then.

Comment: Yes, all blank from 135th to the 95th column for that specific row.

Comment: Then maybe start at column 94 and use `End(xlToRight)`.

Comment: BigBen, I did PCell = Cells(i, "CT").End(xlRight).Address; CT is a column right before the first P column (98th). What do you think? Application-defined, object-defined error pops up.

Comment: `xlToRight`, not `xlRight`.

Comment: Oh my, it is working now!!! (Sorry, I didn't read that comment carefully). My last question for this is where in the code catches just the P columns?

Comment: It doesn't test for that.

Comment: Hmm, okay. I really appreciate your help and time. Also, is there like a rule for how many questions to post in a day? I might have 1 question left to ask today after trying to work it out myself.

Comment: Not that I know of.

Comment: @BigBen BigBen, so when I do the for loop for hundreds of rows, those without x's (blank cells) under the 1st column (x is the blue hyperlink) becomes a hyperlink with the name of the worksheet. How do I prevent that and leave it as blank without creating the hyperlinks?

Comment: Maybe ask a new question, as this chat has gone on probably way too long:)